# How to open a Popup window, so that it's height is from the top of the screen to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to open a popup window, so that it height is from the top of the screen to the "applications" bar of Windows. This is the code:

```
function windowOpener(windowHeight, windowWidth, windowName, windowUri) {

var windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;


var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;


newWindow = window.open(windowUri, windowName, 'resizable=0,scrollbars=1,width=' + windowWidth +
    ',height=' + windowHeight +
    ',left=' + centerWidth);

newWindow.focus();
return newWindow.name;

}
```

Why doesnt it work in IE? (works in chrome)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you only need screen.width and screen.height.  Don't prepend them with window.

**Edit:** Apparently IE requires a "fullscreen=yes" param.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(url) 
{
 params  = 'width='+screen.width;
 params += ', height='+screen.height;
 params += ', top=0, left=0'
 params += ', fullscreen=yes';

 newwin=window.open(url,'windowname4', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}
// -->
</script>

<a href="javascript: void(0)" 
   onclick="popup('popup.html')">Fullscreen popup window</a>
```

Comment: This does make the popup bigger! But do you know how to make it stop at the "applications" bar, where you can see all your open applications in Windows?

Comment: I tried adding scrollbars=1 to the params, but it doesnt seem to work my way: params += ', resizable=0, scrollbars=1'; Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<a class="popme" href="http://codesheet.org">popup</a>
```

jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".popme").click(function(event){
      var h = 650;
      var w = 340;
      var wh = screen.height;
      var ww = screen.width;
      var top = wh/2 - h/2;
      var left = ww/2 - w/2;
      var popup = window.open(this.href + '', 'player', 'height=' + wh + ', width=' + w + ', scrollbars=no, left=' + left + ', top=' + top);
      popup.focus();
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Demo: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/JMbOYCUI

Comment: `var popup = window.open(this.href + '', 'player', 'height=' + wh + ', width=' + w + ', scrollbars=no, left=' + left + ', top=' + top);`  
  
should be  
  `var popup = window.open(this.href + '', 'player', 'height=' + h + ', width=' + w + ', scrollbars=no, left=' + left + ', top=' + top);`

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to open new window in full screen, did you try remove the height and width parameters?

```
newWindow = window.open(windowUri, windowName);
```

[see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)